# Laravel connect 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-5.6

I have 3 tables `tbl_admins`, `tbl_systems`, and `tbl_admin_roles`. How can I connect these three tables if I want the admins to have access in many systems with different roles in each system.

I have already connect `tbl_admins` and `tbl_systems` using an intermediary table `admin_system` (admin and system has a relationship of many to many). Should I create a model for `admin_system` table and connect it with `tbl_admin_roles` using another intermediary table or is there a way that connect those three tables using one intermediary table?

Comment: Read Laravel relationship documentation. I am sure it will give you a better idea! [See here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: After reading the documentation. please tell your relationships you want to build with these three tables.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same intermediary table. 
I'd suggest three main tables tbl_admins, tbl_systems, tbl_roles
Then your intermediary table would have: admin_id, system_id, role_id as Foreign keys.
Then link up the models with the appropriate Eloquent relations in the Laravel docs.

[Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)